# Strange behavior after user clicks adMob ad

Tags: android, admob

I have successfully added admob ads to my android app and can view test ads on the emulator and my development phone (Nexus One). When I click on one of the test ads, it opens the web browser or market to that particular page(gmail or whatever). I click the home button to exit, but when I try to start my app again, it takes me back to the market page or browser that came up when clicking the test ad.

I have a feeling it is something in the onLeaveApplication or onPresentScreen methods implemented with AdListener, but I'm lost and the adMob documentation doesn't provide much info on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is the expected behavior for an application.  If you click home and then back on your application icon, most applications will jump back to the last activity on the stack.  It's certainly possible to kill your application altogether and treat re-entry as a brand new instance of your application, but you probably don't want that either as all user state will be lost unless you explicitly save it, which is even more work.

The AdMob client SDK listener callbacks are all optional for you to implement; there's no expectation that you do anything in particular.  They're there as a convenience for you to pause, save, or resume whatever activity you were doing before.

Users are generally used to hitting the back button to go back to your app, not home and then back into the app.

Comment: I guess I just don't really click ads so I never ran into it, but after clicking ads in other apps (Engadget) they display the same behavior.  Thanks for your answer.